# SyntaxError with print

Tags: python

The code in the interactive shell:

```
>>>password = ''
>>>while password != 'secret':
       password = input('Please password')

print("Right password")
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

I want to make a code where he will ask me to enter the code and i can do it ... But when i press enter  I get the following message.

python3

https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9rv1.jpg

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I see you're a new contributor, so I advise you to check out [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Can you [edit] your question to include the full exception traceback or an indication of which line raises it?

Comment: What he means is that we don't have enough information of your error. Instead of "cleaning it for us", it is better (and easier) to just copy and paste the error messages you got. What's your python version?

Comment: Can you include the version of Python you are using

Comment: Maybe indentation?

Comment: You just need to hit enter one more time to execute your while loop before writing your `print` line. The interpreter thinks you are still writing the `while` block and throws the exception because the indentation is wrong

Comment: But if hit enter one more time then it cant stop asking me so i cant use the print after... i think. @IainShelvington

Comment: Can someone make a gif for this?

Answer (score 6):

Please note input() and print() in Python2.x is a little different with python3.x
Therefore, Check your python version first.

[image: Shot1]

Python2.x:

```
password = raw_input('prompt to user')
print 'hello world'
```

Python3.x:

```
password = input('prompt to user')
print('hello world')
```

Then, when you define a while loop in the command line, you should leave a line empty and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after while loop completed, enter the rest of your code.

[image: shot2]

As I showed in the above picture, I left a line empty then press `enter`, then I entered my rest of codes.

If you wanna run your code in `Python v3`, in the *command prompt* or *Linux shell* enter: python3
If you got error please download the latest version of python
Finally, as others say, please use an IDE like `vscode` and enter your entire code then run it, less trouble!!!
Download VisualStudio Code:
(https://code.visualstudio.com/download).

Answer (score -1):

Python shell doesn't support the complex code. Maybe You can try this.

[Python shell with `while`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIQW3.png)

Anyway, I recommend you to use the script.

Comment: It does. It's only that you have to press enter twice or else it thinks you're still in the while loop

Comment: Yes, the shell supports some simple code, such as a single code block.

Comment: Please include the code as actual code text in your answer. If you feel an image is needed, do so *in addition*.

Comment: But the point is the shell, not the code. I just want to show it. But I am new here, the feeling is so bad.